# Why does it print the same log twice?

Tags: java

I have to do an .upperCase() through a formatter, but I don't understand why it prints the same message but without the upper, since I have established that it uses only that.

I am using java util test.

```java
public DatabaseAccessProxy(String pass, DatabaseAccess database) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        this.logged = false;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.database = database;
        manejador = new ConsoleHandler();   
        fileManejador = new FileHandler("C:/Users/ignac/OneDrive/Escritorio/OO2/Practica 6/logs");
        manejador.setFormatter(new ShoutingSimpleFomatter());
        fileManejador.setFormatter(new JSONFormater());
        Logger.getLogger("app.main").addHandler(manejador);
    }
```

```java
public class ShoutingSimpleFomatter extends SimpleFormatter {
    
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return super.format(record).toUpperCase();
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY INSERTNEWROW
ADVERTENCIA: ACCESO VALIDO PARA LA INSERCION!
may. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.accesobd.DatabaseAccessProxy insertNewRow
ADVERTENCIA: Acceso valido para la insercion!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY GETSEARCHRESULTS
INFORMACIÓN: ACCESO VALIDO PARA LA BUSQUEDA!
may. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.accesobd.DatabaseAccessProxy getSearchResults
INFORMACIÓN: Acceso valido para la busqueda!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY GETSEARCHRESULTS
INFORMACIÓN: ACCESO VALIDO PARA LA BUSQUEDA!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY GETSEARCHRESULTS
INFORMACIÓN: ACCESO VALIDO PARA LA BUSQUEDA!
may. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.accesobd.DatabaseAccessProxy getSearchResults
INFORMACIÓN: Acceso valido para la busqueda!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY GETSEARCHRESULTS
INFORMACIÓN: ACCESO VALIDO PARA LA BUSQUEDA!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY GETSEARCHRESULTS
INFORMACIÓN: ACCESO VALIDO PARA LA BUSQUEDA!
may. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.accesobd.DatabaseAccessProxy getSearchResults
INFORMACIÓN: Acceso valido para la busqueda!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY LOGIN
GRAVE: ACCESO INVALIDO A LA BASE DE DATOS!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY LOGIN
GRAVE: ACCESO INVALIDO A LA BASE DE DATOS!
MAY. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. AR.EDU.UNLP.INFO.OO2.ACCESOBD.DATABASEACCESSPROXY LOGIN
GRAVE: ACCESO INVALIDO A LA BASE DE DATOS!
may. 25, 2022 8:06:42 P. M. ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.accesobd.DatabaseAccessProxy login
GRAVE: Acceso invalido a la base de datos!
```

Comment: I think by default the logger already has a ConsoleHandler installed.  So by adding a second ConsoleHandler you're printing twice.  Try removing the console handler you added and see if you only get one print line.

Comment: @markspace how do i clear or ignore the default consolehandler?

Comment: I added answer below. @imnachox I also don't feel that modifying the propagation of your handler is a better solution though.  Both disable external configuration by a sysop and are kinda on the user hostile side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove unwanted handlers by calling `getHandlers()` and iterating through that list, calling `removeHandler()` on any you don't want.  The default handlers are normally added at the root logger which is named `""` (an empty string).

```
public class LoggerHandlers {
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      // clean slate, remove all
      Logger root = Logger.getLogger( "" );
      Handler[] handlers = root.getHandlers();
      for( Handler h : handlers )
         root.removeHandler( h );
      Logger.getLogger( LoggerHandlers.class.getName() ).warning( "Test" );
   }
   
}
```

However, this is normally a very bad idea.  It prevents a system operator ("sysop") from externally configuring your application.  This is a very user hostile app.  Use this only during debugging when you have no other choice.